# I can't connect to my SQL Server database Using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
Protected Sub login_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login_btn.Click

    Dim connString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim sql As String
    connString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Suivi_Invst;Integrated Security=True"
    sql = "select NET_ID, Password from User"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connString)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While sqlReader.Read()
            If (Password.Text = sqlReader("Password") And NET_ID.Text = sqlReader("NET_ID")) Then
                Response.Redirect("Creation.aspx")
            End If
        End While

        sqlReader.Close()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try

End Sub
```

I always get the msg box saying that connection can noy be established.

I tried to open SQL Server Management Studio at the same time the code running but I didn't anything.

Comment: What exactly does the exception say? Your messagebox does not tell anything...

Comment: It's clear it does say "can not open connection !" don't you see it?

Comment: *What exactly does the exception say? Your messagebox does not tell anything... –  Robert 3 mins ago* *It's clear it does say "can not open connection !" don't you see it? –  el asraoui youness 30 secs ago* I guess using VB.NET was the warning sign...

Comment: whaat? can you explain more?

Comment: we need to know what the `ex.Message` and `ex.StackTrace` values are. Your message doesn't indicate *what* the problem was - only that there *was* a problem

Comment: @Robert asks you: what does the *exception*, not *messagebox* say. Clarification: you're just throwing away actual *exception* text, and this "Can not open connection" text is pretty useless since it has been show on **any** exception inside try/catch block.

Comment: In other words: replace "MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")" with  "MsgBox(ex.ToString())"

Comment: yaa i know, and i dn't get any other exception or error. and when throwing the msg box means that the _try_ part is not being executed at all, like it doesn't exist

Comment: @elasraouiyouness No, it doesn't mean that at all. You need to understand the code you're running before you can ask for useful help. And I suggest you try to be less rude to the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude or anything. we're just discussing the problem. i replaced it by the "MsgBox(ex.ToString())" and  get a long msg, i can't copy  / past it

Comment: ---------------------------
my application
---------------------------
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)

   at

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

   at my_application.Login.login_btn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\YOUNESS\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\my application\my application\Account\Login.aspx.vb:line 22

ClientConnectionId:dfd03c4d-81ce-431f-96ed-360637c22dfd

Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15
--------------------------

Comment: Please don't dump error messages in the comments, there is an edit button on the question, where you can modify the question to include this information.

Comment: Try MsgBox(ex.message) which will give an abbreviated message rather than a full dump which may (or may) not be enough to figure out why the exception has fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Protected Sub login_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login_btn.Click

    Dim connString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim sql As String
    connString = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Suivi_Invst;Integrated Security=True"
//Instead of 
sql = "select NET_ID, Password from User"
//I used this
 sql = "SELECT [NET_ID], [Password] FROM [User] "
```

And it worked

```
    connection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While sqlReader.Read()
            If (Password.Text = sqlReader("Password") And NET_ID.Text = sqlReader("NET_ID")) Then
                Response.Redirect("~/Request/Creation.aspx")
            End If
        End While
        sqlReader.Close()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

From your exception text:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

`User` is **reserved keyword** in SQL Server.

Basically not recommended to create table having name equals to reserved keywords, but if you really need this name, you have to surround it with square brackets in your query like this:

```
select NET_ID, Password from [User]
```

Comment: Password is also a reserved word... so place the square brackets around that too.

Comment: @Mych in fact, when one of columns names is reserved keyword - it is not a problem, and no exception will be thrown when you accessing such a column without escaping by brackets. Yes, it is better to surround such columns in brackets, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Andy, thanks... I was unaware of that my sql knowledge is fairly basic.

Answer (score 0):

I from what I can see your connection string looks like it's creating the error you forget to escape the "\" character.
additional you can move code inside try block so that you get specific error code

so to escape you can change the line to become

connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Suivi_Invst;Integrated Security=True";

**OR**

connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Suivi_Invst;Integrated Security=True";

so update your code to become:

Protected Sub login_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles login_btn.Click

```
Dim connString As String
Dim connection As SqlConnection
Dim command As SqlCommand
Dim sql As String


Try
        connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Suivi_Invst;Integrated Security=True"

 //OR USE BELOW
 //connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Suivi_Invst;Integrated Security=True"
sql = "select NET_ID, Password from User"
connection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While sqlReader.Read()
        If (Password.Text = sqlReader("Password") And NET_ID.Text = sqlReader("NET_ID")) Then
            Response.Redirect("Creation.aspx")
        End If
    End While

    sqlReader.Close()
    command.Dispose()
    connection.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: Look through exception text posted in comments. It is clearly said there: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'". It is exception thrown by SQL Server, so we can conclude that connection was successful and there is no any issues caused by connection string here. Also note that original question was about VB, and there is no `@` escaping of strings in VB, this escaping exists in C#, not VB.

Comment: Ok that's why I added the second escape character

Comment: But I didn't saw the comment with exception.  Sorry.